# Connect to SQL Server Express 2008 R2 from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to SQL Server Express 2008 from Oracle SQL Developer.  When I try to test the connection I keep getting this error:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Unknown server host name 'My-PC\SQLEXPRESS'
```

These are steps I followed.

1) Downloaded `Oracle 11g Express` and installed.

2) Download `Oracle SQL Developer` and installed.

3) Downloaded Third Party JDBC Driver for SQL Server [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/thirdparty-095608.html) and followed the installation instructions.

I already have `SQL Server 2008 Express` running on my machine.  The machine name is `My-PC`.  In the `SQL Server Management Studio` connection the Server name is `.\SQLEXPRESS`

In the `Oracle SQL Developer` `New/Select Database Connection` window, the SQL Server tab is there which indicates that the JDBC driver installed.  This is what I'm entering in the fields:

`Hostname: My-PC\SQLEXPRESS`  (I've also tried, `.\SQLEXPRESS` and `localhost`).

`Port: 1433`

I've tried with `Use Windows Authentication` and without.

Comment: you could solve this??? i have the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable TCP/IP protocol on the SQL Server Configuration Manager (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

And later in Oracle SQL Developer configuration you need to put this on port field:

port:**1433/databasename;instance=SQLEXPRESS**